# Getting 1062, Duplicate entry for key unique constraint key, but there are no rows in database with the data for which unique constraint is added

Tags: python, mysql, django

We are getting 1062, “Duplicate entry" for Key "unique constraint key name" on saving Django Model, whereas there are no existing rows in database with the unique constrained data, for eg: we have added unique together for email and phone number fields, but when we try to save data we are getting duplicate entry.
This is not happening all the time but in some cases, also this happens a lot when database cpu utilization is high , we are using Amazon AWS

Comment: This is not about AWS issue. Show us your code, related model etc

Comment: Please post in TEXT A) your complete query, B) results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (table_name); and C) results of SHOW INDEX FROM (table_name); please.